# Java Time questions

Tags: java, variables, time, integer

In java what is the most effective way to get the time so that you can compare it to another time taken later in the future?

More specifically, how can I get the hours and minutes (separately) of the current time as an integer value (as opposed to a string) to be used to compare later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at using the Java [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, specifically, the `.get(Calendar.HOUR)` and `.get(Calendar.MINUTE)` methods.

Don't store the hour and minute values though, either store an instance of the `Calendar` class, or store the current UNIX timestamp, and compare those, obtaining the hours and minutes after performing the subtraction.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. And the tip after the question was very helpful.

Comment: To elaborate, storing the hour/minute values, then performing the calculation to figure out the difference in time manually is pretty difficult, compared with subtracting two instances of the `Calendar` class, then pulling the hour/minute out.

Answer (score -1):

Convert to unix time, millis from the epoch. Use the `jodatime`, it has more powerful date-time functions. If you want use the JDK only, use `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Vague and unhelpful: asker is clearly a beginner. Someone already had a `Calendar` example up before you posted this answer from the looks of it (althogh I didn't use his answer to compare times!). Is `JodaTime` necessary for simply extracting minutes and hours (which were specifically asked for in the question)? You could explain why if that is the case.